# Extract Filename From Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I m having a Url and i want to extract particular filenames from that url but i have alist of files and want each filename whose urls m getting in the list

Controller Code

```
using (AzureBlobEntities context = new AzureBlobEntities())
        {
            var data = context.UserProfile.Where(d => d.Id == UserId).Select(
             s => new UserProfileModel
             {
                 Id = s.Id,
                 Name = s.Name,
                 Gender = s.Gender,
                 State = s.State,
                 YearOfBirth = s.YearOfBirth,
                 UserVideoList = context.UserVideo.Select
                 (
                    d => new UserVideoModel
                    {
                        VideoUrl = d.VideoUrl
                    }

                 ).ToList()

             }).SingleOrDefault();
            return View(data);
        }
```

This is my query to get user data i have video url stored respect to particular user now at the time of fetching user details i want to fetch his associated files too and get the perfect result but what am i getting is video full urls i just want filenames any help will be appreciated

Comment: From the `VideoUrl` you want to extract the filename ? Is that what you want ?

Comment: https://videodb.blob.core.windows.net/video/7a73d8c3-3ddb-4834-bcf9-71547b8e6f57_IService.docx this is my url i just want filename from it i.e IService.docx